# What is wrong with my code? Invalid type argument of unary. Double pointers

Tags: c, pointers

I just started to learn C and I am getting various errors with pointers. I cannot really find what is the problem with code below. I wasted like a day to resolve this issue and still nothing. It says Invalid type argument of unary. I suspect the reason is in double pointers.  I tried couple of ways of solving it. I tried to put brackets for double pointer before making a comparison and similar things. But nothing helps. 
What is really wrong here? I will appreciate your help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int isEqual(char *line, char *word){
    while(**line == **word && **line && **word){
        (*line)++;
        (*word)++;
    }

    if(**line == **word == '\0') return 1;
    else return 0;
}

int main(){ 

    int i;
    int argc = 2;
    char **lines;
    *lines = "sort";
    (*lines)++;
    *lines = "revs";

 if(isEqual(*lines, "sort")){
        printf("Equal");
    }else{
        printf("Not equal");
    }

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Providing the complete error message would be helpful, since it undoubtedly says which line the error is on and probably says which unary operation is complaining.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Variable `lines` were not initialized

```
char **lines;
```

So the next statement is already invalid

```
*lines = "sort";
```

Also in the function this statement

```
while(**line == **word && **line && **word){
```

is also invalid because you may not two times apply dereferencing to an object defined as `char *`

Function IsEqual is in whole invalid and uses invalid C constructions.

The valid program could look the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>

int isEqual( const char *line, const char *word )
{
    while( *line == *word && *line )
    {
        line++;
        word++;
    }

    return *line == *word;
}

int main( void )
{ 

    char * lines[2];
    lines[0] = "sort";
    lines[1] = "revs";

    if ( isEqual( lines[0], "sort" ) )
    {
        puts( "Equal" );
    }
    else
    {
        puts( "Not equal" );
    }

    if ( isEqual( lines[1], "sort" ) )
    {
        puts( "Equal" );
    }
    else
    {
        puts( "Not equal" );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Or instead of these three statements

```
    char * lines[2];
    lines[0] = "sort";
    lines[1] = "revs";
```

you could write only one statement

```
    char * lines[2] = { "sort", "revs" };
```

The output is

```
Equal
Not equal
```

Comment: Also, the 3-way comparison will not behave as intended (i.e. it'll compare `**line` with a boolean value)

Comment: @Drew McGowen  There are too many errors that to list they all.:)

Comment: why do I need to have const in the argument? is it necessary?

Comment: @PutinHuylo in this case you guarantee that arrays will not be changed in the function and you can pass as arguments const array.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to show us the actual error message, which I presume is something like

```
error: invalid type argument of unary ‘*’ (have ‘int’)
```

The `*` is important, since that's the operator it's complaining about. Please update your question to show the *exact* (copy-and-pasted) error message, and clearly indicate which line of your program it's referring to.

You've defined `line` as an object of type `char*`, so `*line` is of type `char`, and `**line` is illegal (since a `char` is not a pointer).

Changing `**line` to `*line` should at least avoid that error. I haven't taken the time to figure out whether that's the only change you need to make.

(Incidentally, please avoid the phrase "double pointer", which can refer to the type `double*`. Use "pointer to pointer" instead. But you have no pointers to pointers in your `isEqual` function.)

Answer (score 0):

At the beginning

```
int isEqual(char *line, char *word){
    while(**line == **word && **line && **word){
```

When you declare `line` by `char* line`, you are saying `line` is a pointer to a `char` type varible, which means the value of `line` is an address of a `char` type variable.

And when you use a pointer, `*line` means the value of the `char` type variable that `line` is pointing to. So when you use `**line`, it doesn't make any sense because you are trying to fetch a value from the address of value `*line`.

For example, if your `line` points to a `char` type variable with value of 'a', then `**line` is  the value saved at address `0x61`. (Because ascii value for 'a' is 0x61, and C take `char` as `int`)